jenkins build errror to change the directory
I started learning jenkins recently (in linux os) and I tried to run the java file using jenkins, so I configured the job and wrote a shell script to change the directory to which the java file exist.
enter image description here
When it executed, it has given the error that it cannot cd to the directory.
enter image description here.
This is my problem please give me the steps to resolve it.
I am expecting to run the build succesfully.

Does the directory exist on the server where your Jenkins is running? Can you do ls -al /home before you cd?

Yes I have the directory in the path which I have given

Does the user that Jenkins is running as have permissions to access the directory?

yes the user has the permission to access the file

Please add ls -al /home/kali/Desktop to the beginning of your script and share the relevant output.

Running as SYSTEM
Building in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/java
[java] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/jenkins3919486040238926713.sh

ls -al /home/kali/Desktop
ls: cannot access '/home/kali/Desktop': Permission denied
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE

